# Can't get claims from JWT token with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to do a really simple implementation of JWT bearer authentication with ASP.NET Core. I return a response from a controller a bit like this:

```
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, applicationUser.UserName));
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
             _jwtOptions.Issuer,
             _jwtOptions.Audience,
             identity.Claims,
             _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
             _jwtOptions.Expiration,
             _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

       var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

       return new JObject(
           new JProperty("access_token", encodedJwt),
           new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
           new JProperty("expires_in", (int)_jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds),
           new JProperty(".issued", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString())
       );
```

I have Jwt middleware for incoming requests:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
     AutomaticChallenge = true,
     TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});
```

This seems to work to protect resources with the authorize attribute, but the claims never show up.

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var user = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims; // Nothing here
```

Comment: Have you tried `Context.User.Claims`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use `ClaimsPricipal.Current` in an ASP.NET Core application, as it's not set by the runtime. You can read https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/322 for more information.

Instead, consider using the `User` property, exposed by `ControllerBase`.

Answer (score 11):

Access `User.Claims` instead of `ClaimsPrinciple.Current.Claims`.

[From Introduction to Identity at docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html):

> ...inside the `HomeController.Index` action method, you can view the `User.Claims` details.

[Here is the relevant source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L226-L232) from the MVC repository:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal User
{
   get
   {
       return HttpContext?.User;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As part of ASP.NET Core 2.0, you can read the JWT Claims like Shaun described above. If you are only looking for the User Id (make sure you already add it as part of the claim using the "Sub" claim name) then you can use the following to two examples to read depending on your use case:

**Read User ID Claim:**

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName()
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
            //...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

**Read Other Claims:**

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName()
        {
            var rolesClaim = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where( c => c.Type == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType).FirstOrDefault();
            //...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

With this solution, you can access the `User.Identity` and its claims in controllers when you're using JWT tokens:

Step 1: create a JwtTokenMiddleware:

```
public static class JwtTokenMiddleware
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseJwtTokenMiddleware(
      this IApplicationBuilder app,
      string schema = "Bearer")
    {
        return app.Use((async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            IIdentity identity = ctx.User.Identity;
            if (identity != null && !identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await ctx.AuthenticateAsync(schema);
                if (authenticateResult.Succeeded && authenticateResult.Principal != null)
                    ctx.User = authenticateResult.Principal;
            }
            await next();
        }));
    }
}
```

Step 2: use it in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();
}
```

Comment: helpful, although I don't fully understand why. Also, your mind-bending ternary statement there can be simplified to 

```identity != null && !identity.IsAuthenticated```