# Asp.Net Core 2.2 - How to return the Current user ID when using Two AuthorizationSchemes, JWT and cookies

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

Some times authenticating using Login razor page, and sometimes authenticating using Postman, I would like to get the same userId to use in any kind of controller method in the project.

Here is the **static class helper** I am using currently:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static Guid GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var userId =   user.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Subject)?.Value?.Trim();

        return Guid.Parse(userId);
    }

    public static string[] GetRoles(ClaimsPrincipal identity)
    {
        return identity.Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Placing a breakpoint at GetUserId method above, 
when using Cookie scheme, the correct Id is returned, but when using JWT scheme GetUserId gets null value.

I've tested previously other ways that either didn't work for both. So what is the shortest implementation that works for both ?

**Edit:**

Following @ChrisPratt suggestion, changed GetUserId method as follows:

```
public static Guid GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
  var userId = Guid.Parse(user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
  return userId;
}
```

But when hover the mouse on user -> Identity -> Claims, I get Count = 0

So now as no Claims can be used [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290895/1299388), how can I write the above class with `User` property exposed by `ControllerBase` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried, but regardless of auth scheme, the end result should be a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance on your `HttpContext`. The way you'd usually get the user id is to simply get the `NameIdentifier` claim:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Comment: Sorry this answer didn't work, I get error: User doesn't contain a definition for FindFirstValue, also introducing HTTPContext would need to convert the class to non static, which would trigger a lot of changes in the project code.

Comment: You need to add a using. Aside from that, if it requires changes, make them. You shouldn't be using statics in the first place. That, and if this is a library, you'd simply pass in the user id from some place that does have HttpContext (controller, etc). The library should absolutely not have knowledge about how a user ID is retrieved from the system.

Comment: I've edited the question for more accuracy, please take a look.